# Getting input from Win32 edit box[C++]

Tags: c++, winapi

Hello all I have been trying to get input from a Win32 text edit box like so:

```
    char IP_ADDR[200];
    char NICK[200];
    #define Print(msg) print_line(*hwnd, msg)
    #define Println() Print("\r\n")


        Print("Welcome to Basic Client 0.01 Alpha!");
        Println();
        Print("Please enter your IP address");
        Println();
        for (;; Sleep(500))
        {
            if (IsKeyDown(VK_RETURN))
            {
                GetDlgItemText(*hwnd, IDC_MAIN_EDIT2, IP_ADDR, sizeof(IP_ADDR));
                SetDlgItemText(*hwnd, IDC_MAIN_EDIT2, "");
                break;
            }
        }
        Print("Please enter a nickname");
        Println();

        for (;; Sleep(500))
        {
            if (IsKeyDown(VK_RETURN))
            {
                GetDlgItemText(*hwnd, IDC_MAIN_EDIT2, NICK, sizeof(NICK));
                SetDlgItemText(*hwnd, IDC_MAIN_EDIT2, "");
                break;
            }
        }
```

But this does not go into a loop or stop it till the key is pressed it just keeps going If it helps I have the run function which this is code is from in a new thread so that it can do this while managing the window messages here is the code for this:

```
Client * c = new Client;
.....
int Run(HWND *hwnd)
{
    MSG msg = { 0 };
    while (msg.message != WM_QUIT)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {

            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
            _beginthreadex(0, 0, ClientThread, (void*)hwnd, 0, 0);

        }


    }

    return 1;
}

unsigned int __stdcall ClientThread(void*data)
{

    HWND *hwnd = (HWND*)data;


    c->Run(hwnd);
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the IsKeyDown function:

```
bool Client::IsKeyDown(int vk)
{
    return ((GetAsyncKeyState(vk) & 0x1) != 0)? true:false;
}
```

Comment: You're creating a thread for every message you receive?  That seems like a bad idea.

Comment: I needed it to handle two things at once and I had no idea how to do that without putting it in the loop

Comment: Why does your `Run` function takes a `HWND*` instead of a simple `HWND`?

Comment: I thought functions could only take pointers to a window so it could actually be used but I guess not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow my bad guys I put the beginThread in the Message loop as Retired Ninja Pointed out and That was what was causing all of the problems.

Comment: That's wrong. Utterly. You are breaking threading rules. Access UI objects from the thread that created the window. You don't need threads here. Make it your goal to write this code without threads.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I will do it